# MongoDB MapReduce. $exists on nested field

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to execute map-reduce operation on specific documents from MongoDB.

Let's say, we have this "document":

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c:{}
    }
  }
}
```

I want to select only those documents, that have an ***a.b.c*** field. From [this documentation page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) I know, that $exists operator can help.

To check, that ***a*** exists I should use:

```
query: {
  a: { $exists : true }
}
```

But what query should I use for nested field, described before?

```
query: {
  //?
}
```

Comment: try: query: {
  'a.b.c': { $exists : true }
}

Comment: This really does not need an answer. You possibly are unaware  of "dot notation" as has been pointed out by @Disposer. There are many examples to search on in the documentation as well as on this very site.

Comment: @NeilLunn, yes, I wasn't aware. Didn't find any examples of dot notation yet.

Answer (score 23):

This isn't related to the fact of using map-reduce.

```
query: {
  'a.b.c' : { $exists : true }
}
```

So is a standard query on an embedded document:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#embedded-documents

Comment: as @Disposer stated in the comment above, donnot forget the quote marks surrounding a.b.c!